# Is this conditional correct? If so, why?

Tags: future

"If their flight hasn't been delayed, they will have arrived by now."

Is this conditional correct?  If so, why?

Comment: Hello Elisa, and welcome to English Language and Usage. Unless you specify which part of the sentence you are suspicious of, this question looks like a proofreading chore. However, I recommend you put a _would_ in place of the "will" in the second clause.

Comment: Hello Cascabel, Thank you for your quick response, I really appreciate it! Is "will have arrived," incorrect? Normally, I use "would" but an Oxford grammar book exercise I just completed shows (doesn't explain) this conditional sentence as correct

Comment: The book is not wrong, but Cascabel has helped you not sound like a book. In other words, the book used an example to show how to use that odd form in English, but not how to fit such constructions into a conversation with English speakers.

Comment: Sorry Elisa, now that I look closer, I realize that "hasn't" was there, which I read as a _hadn't_. @YosefBaskin is right, and that _is_ an odd construction. I am going to upvote your question, and possibly somone will come along to give a better explanation of the usage.

Answer (score 1):

In the Little, Brown Handbook, it says, "Not all clauses beginning with 'if' express conditions contrary to fact. In the sentence "If Joe is out of town, he hasn't heard the news," the verb "is" is correct because the clause refers to a condition presumed to exist. This sentence nicely parallels yours. I don't think either sentence is a true conditional (subjunctive), but both sentences are correct. If your sentence were "If their flight hadn't been delayed, they would have arrived by now," the "would" would indicate a conditional.

But is it a sentence that one would use? Imagine if you're waiting for an arriving friend in the passenger loading zone of an airport. You don't know if their flight has arrived, but you're hoping that it has. Maybe the friend is in customs or baggage claim. You say to someone in the car. "If their flight hasn't been delayed, they will have arrived by now." Sounds fine to me.

Fowler says on subjunctives, "The word is very variously used in grammar; so it will be well to explain ...  it is taken to mean the use of a verb form different from that of the indicative mood in order to denote an action or state as conceived (and not as a fact) and [expressing] a wish, command, exhortation, or a contingent, hypothetical or prospective event." Fowler goes on to say, "About the subjunctive, so delimited [there's the rub], the important general facts are " (1) that it is moribund except in a few easily specified uses; (2) that, owing to the capricious influence of the much analyzed classic moods upon the less studied native, it probably never would have been possible to draw up a satisfactory table of the English subjunctive uses; (3)  that assuredly no one will ever find it possible or worth while to do so now that the subjunctive is dying ...."

Comment: The second clause is future  perfect.

Comment: I have  the Little, Brown Handbook, but I feel "If Joe is out of town" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> If their flight hasn't been delayed, they will have arrived by now.

This is an example of a conditional sentence that does not talk about *irrealis* or an "unreal" or contrary-to-fact situation.

In this sentence, the speaker is simply stating his ignorance as to whether the flight was delayed; he's not saying it was; he's not saying it wasn't; he's also  not saying anything contrary to fact. Ignorance of an event is not contrary to fact. So we use normal "indicative mood" in both clauses. We don't backshift in the if-clause, nor take a step back from reality in the then-clause by using a modal.

Comment: I can't determine from your answer whether the sentence is correct or incorrect. Apply your reasoning to this: "If their flight never left, they will have arrived by now."